# Sort a String list by String length

Tags: sorting, haskell

I want to sort a list of `String` first by the length of the strings, and if the length is the same then it should sort lexically. I thought I could use the `Data.List` library and write my own compare function that does that. So the compare function should take a list of `String` as the argument and compare all the the elements (which are `String`s). A compare function for `String`s would look like this

```
comp a b
    | length a > length b   = GT
    | length a < length b   = LT
```

How could I address all the list elements with such a function?

Comment: [`sortBy `](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:sortBy)[`(comparing `](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing)[`length)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:length). Look at the type signatures to understand how this works. (BTW, this is pretty inefficient: `length` is slow, so a better approach would be to compute all the lengths once and sort that list in the usual way.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First of all**, your `cmp` function does not handle the case where the lengths are equal: you need to add that. Otherwise you'll get an runtime pattern match error:

```
comp a b
    | length a > length b   = GT
    | length a < length b   = LT
    | otherwise             = undefined  -- TODO
```

also, note that this implementation sometimes computes the length twice, but it's likely that GHC optimizes this one away on its own, and we'll get to solving this later on more fundamentally anyway.

**Then**, once you've fixed your `comp`, all you need to do is pass it to `Data.List.sortBy` together with the list of strings you want to sort. An ipmplementation like that is provided below (`<$>` is the operator alias of `fmap` which works the same as `map` does on lists).

**However**, there's a better solution where you first compute the length of all elements in the list, by mapping each of the elements into a pair where the first member is the original string and the second one is its length. You then use a modified `comp` function that takes 2 pairs instead of just 2 strings, but otherwise behaves the same as your original `comp`. However, you then need to map the intermediate list back to just containing the strings (which is what the `fst <$>` is for, which is equivalent to `map fst` but, again, uses the, IMO nicer looking, `<$>` opetator).

---

So the somewhat **naive solution** would be:

```
sortByLenOrLex :: [String] -> [String]
sortByLenOrLex as = sortBy cmp as where
  cmp a b | n > m     = GT
          | n < m     = LT
          | otherwise = compare a b
    where n = length a
          m = length b
```

and the **more efficient** one, as leftaroundabout points out, would be:

```
sortByLenOrLex' :: [String] -> [String]
sortByLenOrLex' as = fst <$> sortBy cmp (addLen <$> as) where
  cmp (a,n) (b,m) | n > m     = GT
                  | n < m     = LT
                  | otherwise = compare a b
  addLen x = (x, length x)
```

where the list is first amended with the lengths of each of its elements, so as to avoid duplicate, expensive `length` calls.

**EDIT:** please see [chi's answer](/questions/33316573/sort-a-string-list-by-string-length/33318240#33318240) for a much nicer implementation of this algorithm!

---

**Furthermore:**

You can make your functions generic by making them operate on **lists of lists of `Ord`**:

```
sortByLenOrLex'' :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLenOrLex'' as = fst <$> sortBy cmp (addLen <$> as) where
  cmp (a,n) (b,m) | n > m     = GT
                  | n < m     = LT
                  | otherwise = compare a b
  addLen x = (x, length x)
```

this gives you:

```
*Main> sortByLenOrLex'' [[1,2], [1,3], [1,2,3]]
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,2,3]]
```

...and if you want to make it as generic as possible, you can sort **lists of `Foldable` of `Ord`**:

```
sortByLenOrLex''' :: (Foldable f, Ord a) => [f a] -> [f a]
sortByLenOrLex''' as = unamend <$> sortBy cmp (amend <$> as) where
  cmp (a,n,a') (b,m,b') | n > m     = GT
                        | n < m     = LT
                        | otherwise = compare a' b'
  amend    x      = (x, length x, toList x)
  unamend (x,_,_) =  x
```

this gives you:

```
*Main> sortByLenOrLex''' [Just 3, Just 4, Just 3, Nothing]
[Nothing,Just 3,Just 3,Just 4]

*Main> sortByLenOrLex''' [(4,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,1),(3,1)]
[(4,1),(1,1),(1,1),(3,1),(1,2)]

*Main> sortByLenOrLex''' [Left "bla", Right "foo", Right "foo", Right "baz"]
[Left "bla",Right "baz",Right "foo",Right "foo"]

*Main> sortByLenOrLex''' [(3,"hello"),(2,"goodbye"),(1,"hello")]
[(2,"goodbye"),(3,"hello"),(1,"hello")]
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant of @Erik's solution, using some combinators from the library:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow

sortByLen = map snd . sort . map (length &&& id)
```

This is essentially a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: how obvious! but I guess my `sortByLenOrLex'''` cannot be shortened this way?

Comment: @ErikAllik `fmap (snd . snd) . sort . fmap (length &&& (toList &&& id))` should work if you also have `Ord (f a)`.